# How to swallow Exception by IInterceptionBehavior?

Tags: c#, unity-container, enterprise-library

I have a IInterceptionBehavior like blow:

```
public class TraceBehavior : IInterceptionBehavior
{
    public IEnumerable<Type> GetRequiredInterfaces()
    {
        return Type.EmptyTypes;
    }

    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Invoke method:{0}",input.MethodBase.ToString()));
        IMethodReturn result = getNext()(input, getNext);
        if (result.Exception == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invoke successful!");
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Invoke faild, error: {0}", result.Exception.Message));
            result.Exception = null;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public bool WillExecute { get { return true; } }
}
```

Regardless of whether I put it upon methods or not, exception throw always. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code looks OK but you haven't shown how the interception is registered and how the object is being called.

Assuming that interception is being called then if I were to guess it would be that that the method invoked returns a value type and `IMethodReturn.ReturnValue` is null which is causing a `NullReferenceException`.

If that is the case then perhaps returning the default value for a value type would solve your issue:

```
public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Invoke method:{0}", input.MethodBase.ToString()));
    IMethodReturn result = getNext()(input, getNext);
    if (result.Exception == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invoke successful!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Invoke faild, error: {0}", result.Exception.Message));
        result.Exception = null;

        Type type = ((MethodInfo)input.MethodBase).ReturnType;

        if (type.IsValueType)
        {
            result.ReturnValue = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: hi, getNext() get handle and invoke by Invoke method. as getNext().Invoke(input, getNext). I'm wondering what happened in invoked method, suppose it,  target method throwed exception and carry it in result.Exception? How can I define "compile time" aspect?